# How can I solve this issue IAP(InAppPurchase)billing in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am used to develop the app using InAppPurchase(IAP) billing api .
I already uploading app it's works fine. After 1 month i run the previously uploaded app in my Eclipse shown the following dialog shown 
    please see the below screenshot once

> Error
>   This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information.

[image]

I didn't understand what mistake I've done.

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing signed APK? To test InApp purchase you need to use signed APK. I got the same error when i installed unsigned apk in device. Also make sure you have updated google play installed in your device.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create google developer account where you will get api key and you can download inapp jar.
Visit : https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html?hl=d

Comment: i want some modifications in myapp .but i run it always showing the dialog in previously working fine

Comment: inAppBilling = new InAppBilling(activity, SongsAdapter.this, applicationPublicKey, PURCHASE_REQUEST_CODE);
 inAppBilling.startServiceConnection(InAppBilling.ITEM_TYPE_ONE_TIME_PURCHASE,
    PRODUCT_SKU, InAppBilling.ACTIVITY_TYPE_PURCHASE); for buy a product